# how to deploy Odoo to be fit on my server random memory?

Tags: server, config, odoo, ram, odoo-11

i'am installed odoo in digital-ocaen droplet with 4 G of RAM ,
if more than 5 users loign to the system connection lost till restart odoo server to restore the connection

```
 imit_memory_hard = 2684354560
 limit_memory_soft = 2147483648
 limit_request = 8192
 limit_time_cpu = 60
 limit_time_real = 120
 limit_time_real_cron = -1
```

how can i compute the lilit memory ber user or what shall i do to solve the problem

Comment: Are you using a reverse proxy such as Apache or nginx?

Comment: no till now , but i'll use that maybe later

Comment: What does the log say? Run Odoo with --logfile <file> switch, replicate the problem and then copy and paste from 5 lines before the first ERROR message.